# Facebook Login: Javascript and PHP Example

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I was hoping that someone had a current example of using the Facebook Javascript SDK to login and then using te PHP SDK to handle the session the rest of the time.

I've been Googling and trawling the web for an accurate, working example but they all seem to have some limitations or bugs.

I'm finding that after logging in with JS, the PHP seems to fail to find the session more often than not. I can see a FBRS cookie has been set and is always active but this doesn't seem to help.

Really tearing my hair out with this one...

Cheers

Comment: Seems like this is an issue with Facebook's latest policy changes. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/404450666302585

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all my problems with the sessions were because of this bug: developers.facebook.com/bugs/404450666302585

I've updated to the latest PHP-SDK version and everthing seems to be alright.